# animated webp only has key frame？

Tags: ffmpeg, webp

I want to cover a mp4 to animated webp, so I use the following `ffmpeg` command:

My mp4 file is from http://myvideodata.oss-cn-shenzhen.aliyuncs.com/crs_bcb3f246273d4dbb8ec7f93239fbea6e.mp4

```
ffmpeg -i ./test.mp4 test.webp
```

It is ok, and [animated webp](http://myvideodata.oss-cn-shenzhen.aliyuncs.com/crs_bcb3f246273d4dbb8ec7f93239fbea6e.ts.webp) has been created, so I use `webpinfo` tool (downloaded from https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/download and build example in it, or use this one http://myvideodata.oss-cn-shenzhen.aliyuncs.com/webpinfo)

```
webpinfo test.webp
```

and get information like this:

```
RIFF HEADER:
  File size: 1968244
Chunk VP8X at offset     12, length     18
  ICCP: 0
  Alpha: 1
  EXIF: 0
  XMP: 0
  Animation: 1
  Canvas size 362 x 330
Chunk ANIM at offset     30, length     14
  Background color:(ARGB) ff ff ff ff
  Loop count      : 1
Chunk ANMF at offset     44, length  25116
  Offset_X: 0
  Offset_Y: 0
  Width: 362
  Height: 330
  Duration: 42
  Dispose: 0
  Blend: 0
Chunk VP8  at offset     68, length  25092
  Width: 362
  Height: 330
  Alpha: 0
  Animation: 0
  Format: Lossy (1)
```

Every frame size is about 25k, my question is: all frames in animated webp are key frames?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all frames are marked as key frames by the `libwebp_anim` encoder.

Comment: i search on google page, but can not find any information about it , can you show me a link?

Comment: I checked the source - the flag is set unconditionally at https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/89a0d33e3a53e8edefd734b131a7035d13052947/libavcodec/libwebpenc.c#L65